# What exactly defer do?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I placed `scrollIntoView()` to make my grid scroll visible. When I add new grid in gridContainer so I using this method. This is working I can check from debugger. 
my `scrollIntoView()`

```
grid.body.dom.scrollIntoView();
```

But once it reached in defer function it not `scrollIntoView()`  functioning. Can anybody please suggest how to skip this. What defer do and how to skip this. Also I am using `grid.focus()` and again same thing is happening. Grid is coming into view but after come out from debugger no showing into view.

```
defer: function(fn, millis, scope, args, appendArgs) {
  fn = Ext.Function.bind(fn, scope, args, appendArgs);
  if (millis > 0) {
    return setTimeout(function() {
      if (Ext.elevateFunction) {
        Ext.elevateFunction(fn);
      } else {
        fn();
      }
    }, millis);
  }
  fn();
  return 0;
},
```

Comment: `defer` is essentially like a `setTimeout`. However I'm not really clear on the rest of your question.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli What I need to do if I don't want timeout. I am giving `grid.body.dom.scrollIntoView();` in my grid after some time this code is not working.

Comment: There's not enough information, what is causing the `defer` call? Why aren't you using the scroller API? `grid.body.dom` isn't the right thing to be scrolling.

Comment: ok, let me check scroll APIs.

Comment: I can not use any other Api because "Scrolls this element into view within the passed container." is only possible by `scrollIntoView`

Comment: That doesn't sound right. The grid body itself isn't scrollable.

Comment: yes, But I need to make scrollable with respect to parent container. and this only I found in doc of scrollIntoView

Comment: Could you create a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor) that shows your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround would be not to scroll to the component, but to use the [card layout](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/modern/Ext.layout.Card.html) for the center container and display the new grid on an other card.

```
var centerCt;  // reference to your center container
var centerLayout = centerContainer.getLayout();
var newGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {});
centerCt.add(newGrid);
centerLayout.setActiveItem(newGrid);
```

I created a [Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1ph5).

Comment: I am using vbox and when I changing to card no second grid is loading. Well let me try this whatever you written in answer and get back to you in some time.

Comment: This won't work, because at once I am showing only one grid here. I need my panel to be scrollable.